# What is the difference between squared returns and variance?

Tags: volatility, returns, variance, moving-average, forecasting

I am trying to calculate 1-day ahead volatility forecasts using the exponentially weighted moving average, however I am unsure on how to read the formula provided within Risk-Metrics Technical Documentation for one day ahead forecasts. That formula is

$σ_{1,t+1|t}^2=λ σ_{1,t|t-1}^2+(1-λ) r_{1,t}^2$

(This is equation 5.3 on page 81 of [this document](https://www.msci.com/documents/10199/5915b101-4206-4ba0-aee2-3449d5c7e95a))

Can someone please explain the difference between the variance and the squared returns? Both of these components are required for the calculation, however I was using squared returns as my variance for the series. 
Thanks

Comment: Can you remind me what "the formula provided within risk-metrics for one day ahead forecasts" looks like.

Comment: σ_(1,t+1|t)^2=λσ_(1,t|t-1)^2+(1-λ) r_(1,t)^2. Apologies for the format, a more eligible version can be found on page 81 within the attached document: https://www.msci.com/documents/10199/5915b101-4206-4ba0-aee2-3449d5c7e95a

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This equation shows how you update your forecast. (In a word: recursively).

At the close of business on day t, when the day's return $r_{1,t}$ becomes available, you take a weighted average of:

- The forecast you had made yesterday for today, $σ_{1,t|t-1}^2$. (Hopefully you wrote that number down yesterday and you still have the piece of paper on which you wrote it down, otherwise you are in trouble).
- and, the square return for today

the number you thus compute is your forecast $σ_{1,t+|t}^2$ for tomorrow.

(So *you* are computing this time series of $\sigma^2$ values, it is not a variance taken from somewhere else and used in the calculation).

The justification for this method is what @phdstudent said, namely that the expected $r$ is negligible and so is being left out of the calculation.

Answer (score 9):

Usually the formula for the sample variance of a stock is given by:

\begin{equation}
Var(R_{i}) =  E (R_t - E(R_t))^2 
\end{equation}

If you are using daily data to compute the variance then the second term: $E(R_t) \approx  0$, therefore you can drop it from the computation. Which yields:

\begin{equation}
Var(R_{i}) \approx  E (R_t)^2 
\end{equation}

With weekly, monthly, annual data this is no longer a good approximation.

Comment: Just to give a couple of numbers. I've just checked, and since July 1962 the average daily return (i.e. $E[r]$) for the SP500 is 0.03%, the average squared return (i.e. $E[r^2]$) is 0.01%. So indeed $E[r]^2$ is small (about 0.00001%) compared to $E[r^2]$. The daily variance of returns is 0.01% and the daily volatility is about 1%.

Comment: Thanks for the responses so far. The expected return for the daily prices dataset t I am using is 0.000012%, so I think its fair to use the assumption that this value is equal to zero for the rest of the study.       σ_(1,t+1|t)^2=λσ_(1,t|t-1)^2+(1-λ) r_(1,t)^2. This is the formula that I am using for the out of sample forecasts. Apologies for the format, a more eligible version can be found on page 81, within https://www.msci.com/documents/10199/5915b101-4206-4ba0-aee2-3449d5c7e95a.